# player goes through walls while jumping (JAVA)

Tags: java

I am trying to make a donkey kong game. 
Currently, I have a boolean called jump which tells that game if the player is jumping or not, when the space bar is pressed.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        StartJump();
    }
}
```

StartJump: Makes the sprite start jumping by changing velocity. It also changes the jump boolean to true.

```
public void StartJump() {
    if (onground) {
        velocityY = -4;
        onground = false;
        jump = true;
    }
}
```

KeyReleased:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        EndJump();
    }
}
```

EndJump: Sets jump to false

```
public void EndJump() {
    if(velocityY < -6.0)
       velocityY = -6;
    jump = false;
}
```

The problem occurs when you hold down the spacebar, jump is set to true.
Which then causes the forloop which sets the Y position of Mario to not work and he falls through the floor.

Loop: bricks just contains rectangles for Mario to stand on

```
for(int i = 0; i < bricks.size(); i++) {
        if(marHitBox.intersects(bricks.get(i)) && !mario.getClimb() && !mario.getJump() && marHitBox.intersects(jump.get(i))) {
            mario.setMarY((int)bricks.get(i).getY()-40);
            mario.setVeloY(0f);
            mario.setOnGround(true);
        }    
    }
```

It is the !mario.getJump() that is causing the problem. Is there any way to see if the spacebar is held for more than x milliseconds to make jump = false?

Comment: Maybe it's me but your question/code confuses me. Where is the for loop called when spacebar is pressed?

Comment: Much better if you could create a new program just for your question, a [mcve] that is compilable, runnable, and shows the problem directly for us.

Comment: Method names should NOT start with an upper case character! Can you show me a method from the API that does? Follow Java conventions and don't make up your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try measuring the passing time between the spacebar is pressed and released, it will fit your need.

Comment: I tried that, the problem with that is the value is calculated after spacebar is released. By the time the spacebar is released Mario has already went through some floors.

Answer (score 0):

I think just a check would make it go away

```
public void StartJump(){

    if (!jump && onground){
        velocityY = -4;
        onground = false;
        jump = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you use exacly the code that i posted?

Comment: Yes I copied it from the answer you put